# Exporting from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I need Access to export information to Excel using VBA with the following formatting:

1. grab a row and certain columns relating to that row
2. spit it out in Excel
3. loop that process for each row while creating a new sheet for each row in Excel

To be more specific each row is going to be a different location (ex: dallas, chicago...) and I just want to pull certain info from each location and create a spreadsheet for EACH location.

Comment: im sorry... so based off of my data i want a new sheet created for each cell a(1)-a(x), and all of the corresponding data related to each of those cells, all while going the data is re-arranged to match a template i already created.

Answer (score 2):

You do not give much information about your requirement so this is just an introduction.  I can supply more information if you do.

Within the Access VBA editor, select `Tools` then `References`.  Scroll down to `Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library` and select it by clicking the box against it.

Skeleton of required code:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

' I hold my Excel file in the same folder asmy Access database.
' This gets me the name of the folder holding my database.
Path = Application.CurrentProject.Path

' I assume the Excel file already exists  
DestName = Path & "\" & "xxxxxxxx.xls"

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
With xlApp
  .Visible = True         ' This slows your macro but helps during debugging
  '.Visible = False
  Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open(DestName)
  With xlWB
    With .Sheets("Sheet1")
      ' Intro to syntax
      ' *  .Cells(Row,Column) gives access to any cell within the sheet.
      ' *  .Cells(Row,Column).Value gives read/write access to the value.
      ' *  .Cells(Row,Column).Font.Bold = True sets the cell to bold.
      ' *  RowLast = .Cells(Row.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row get the number of the
      '    last used row in column A.
      .Cells(1, 1).Value = "A"

      ' More statements here

    End With
    .Save           ' Save updated workbook to disc
    .Close          ' Close workbook
  End With
  Set xlWB = Nothing    ' Clear reference to workbook
  .Quit         ' Exit Excel
End With
Set xlApp = Nothing     ' Clear reference to Excel
```

Comment: I think I would be inclined to run a series of queries with transfer spreadsheet and the same workbook name. Once the queries have different names (Chicago etc) they will be placed in a new sheet, or existing sheet of the same name, and such queries will, I think be easier for future maintenance.

Comment: im sorry...
so based off of my data i want a new sheet created for each cell a(1)-a(x), and all of the corresponding data related to each of those cells, all while going the data is re-arranged to match a template i already created.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand how these two questions relate.  In your other question you transfer the result of a query to an Excel workbook using an Access function.  Doesn't that work?  What are you asking for here that is different.  Why did you ask a second question rather than improve this one?

Answer (score 0):

'This code selects the specific rows of data into a temporary access table, then exports the temp table to an excel spreadsheet, then drops the temporary access table.

```
Private Sub btnXLS_Click()

    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    db.Execute "select * into TempTbl from SourceTable where Fieldname = " & Values & ""

    Dim outputFileName As String
    outputFileName = "C:filename_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xls"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "TempTbl", outputFileName, True

    On Error Resume Next
        db.Execute "DROP TABLE TempTbl"

    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```